# is there a way to push linker output(MAP file) to separate log file in cmake

Tags: cmake, ninja

I am working in an embedded project with cmake version 3.18.5. The make file of type ninja.
The command `ninja > log.txt` is adding all the log information(file name, warning) along with Map file into `log.txt`. I don't want the map file info in `log.txt`
I want the linker output(i.e Map file info) to a separate file and it should not pollute the main log file.

Comment: By adding some flag to the linker command, you could filter Map file info from its output. But `ninja` itself definitely has no option for filter output of inner commands. If you are looking for CMake solution, then you need to show us an example of your project and platform settings. In current form I can only guess what is the "Map file info".

Comment: is there a way to push all the log of linker to a separate file ?@Tsyvarev